# Template Template Parameters in the C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Which templates (if any) in the C++ standard library have one or more template template parameters?

If there are many, then a couple of examples is fine.

If C++ version matters, then the latest draft of C++14/C++1y is preffered.

Comment: Some templates of containers have template constructors.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: a constructor template is not a template template parameter.

Comment: I think there aren't template template parameters templates in STL. Because this would break the philosophy of `Containers <-> Iterators <-> Algorithms`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos a quick ad-hoc peruse of the C++11 standard reveals no first-term template-template arguments (i.e. something of the form `template<template<...`. I didn't take the time to write up a full and proper RE to scan the entire standard, but I think 40two is perhaps correct, that no standard-lib actual usage exists. I don't have a v14 draft handy; sorry about that.

Comment: Same as @WhozCraig, did not find any occurence of template template parameter in the standards (N3337).

Comment: There aren't any because template template parameters are really awkward (especially before C++11) and the standard silently acknowledges that ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes By that you mean "It acknowledges that with silence".  ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of any templates in the C++ standard library that are specified to take a template template parameter, but there is at least one standard template in C++11 that has a *partial specialization* with a template template parameter: `std::pointer_traits`. `std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::element_type` is specified to be:

> `Ptr::element_type` if such a type exists; otherwise, `T` if `Ptr` is a class template instantiation of the form `SomePointer<T, Args>`, where `Args` is zero or more type arguments; otherwise, the
>   specialization is ill-formed.

In order to implement this you need a template template parameter for `SomePointer`, because it can be an arbitrary class template (as long as it only has type template parameters, to be precise). Here is the libstdc++ helper class partial specialization that does this, for instance:

```
  template<template<typename, typename...> class _SomePtr, typename _Tp,
            typename... _Args>
    struct __ptrtr_elt_type<_SomePtr<_Tp, _Args...>, false>
    {
      typedef _Tp __type;
    };
```

Comment: Strictly speaking an implementation must conform to the described behaviour, which in this case doesn’t explicitly mention a partial specialization. They can do so any which way so they could e.g. choose to perform magicks. In either case, the user is not allowed to detect whether such a specialization is present or not.